# Identify duplicate rows and only set specific columns to zero

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I try to identify duplicate rows in a data frame and according to that only set a specific column x of the duplicated row to 0. If the columns id and key are the same, I try to set the columns x & y to zero, if there is also the same number (bigger than 0) for the duplicated rows.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,3,2,0,0,0,0), y=c(1,0,1,1,4,4,3,0), id=c('id1','id1','id1','id1','id2','id2','id2','id2'), key=c('key1','key1','key1','key1','key2','key2','key2','key3'))
df[order(df$id),]
duplicates <- df[duplicated(df[c('id','key')]) & (df$x != 0 | df$y != 0),]
```

With that, I was able to identify the duplicate rows, but now I want to only set the specific columns (x or y) to zero if there is the same value as well. I tried it with an ifelse statement, but I wasn't able to get it correct.

The desired output would look like this (only one value in column x and tree values in column y set to 0):

```
output <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,0,2,0,0,0,0), y=c(1,0,0,0,4,0,3,0), id=c('id1','id1','id1','id1','id2','id2','id2','id2'), key=c('key1','key1','key1','key1','key2','key2','key2','key3'))
output[order(output$id),]
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  group_by(id, key, y) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(sequence(n()) > 1, 0, y)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(id, key, x) %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(sequence(n()) > 1, 0, x))
```

Edit: is this what you are looking for? Let me know what you think as I wasn't sure what exactly you were asking

Comment: I edited the data frame for a more general approach if I want to keep all different values in y (general applicable for more than 1 value). What would be the necessary changes in; sequence(n()) > 1?